# How to say "small of the back" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

In English the lumbar region of the back is known as "the small of the back." Besides "región lumbar", does Spanish also have a non-technical term for this part of the body?

Comment: _Espalda baja_ or _parte baja de la espalda_ would be acceptable I think.

Comment: **Espalda baja** or **Zona lumbar** are the ones I know.

Comment: @DGaleano *zona lumbar* is the best way I think.

Comment: In Spain we use to say "las lumbares": _Me duelen **las lumbares**_.

Answer (score 3):

The "small of the back" is known in Spanish as:

> Espalda baja
>
> Zona lumbar
>
> Las lumbares (in Spain - see @Ra_ comment).